# pandas not reading new/blank/fresh book1.xlsx

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm just trying to open ANY xlsx file with pandas and I get a whole string of errors.  I can even create a brand new blank book1.xlsx and it will error out.

my code to try to read a xlsx file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

...just gets me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\In\hockey4.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 307, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 394, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 141, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 808, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 265, in process_stream
    meth(self, elem)
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 392, in do_sheet
    sheet = Sheet(bk, position=None, name=name, number=sheetx)
  File "C:\Users\FRED1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.extract_formulas = book.extract_formulas
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, as I'm JUST learning as of today, but I have tried everything I see and I can't get past just OPENING the file.  I need the xlsx version for the formatting that I'm trying to do (which I have tried to do with xlrt, but fail to get working as well as I can get with xlsx files).  The fix I am using is just resaving the xlsx file as a xls file and reading it in without any issues.  I haven't figured out how to SAVE a xls file correctly OR read a xlsx file.  Crazy, I know.  Anyone feel like helping me get started here?

Comment: FYI, python 3.7.1 and a fresh pandas module install, in a windows 7 environment

Comment: Could you print these two things in a Python shell?  `import xlrd; xlrd.__VERSION__`, `pd.__version__`.

Comment: ('1.0.0', '0.23.4')

Comment: So, after getting some help from the reddit community /r/learnpython, I uninstalled everything  associated with python and did a fresh install of 3.6 (had some folks saying that 3.7 might have some issues).  I can now open an xlsx file using the pd.read_excel() command!